# Loop skips every second item when removing selected items from many to many

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my application I am trying to remove many to many records via loop:

```
org = current_user.Organization
for item in org.items:
        if item.id in remove_ids:
            org.items.remove(item)
db.session.commit()
```

However, it skips every second item. Since the list is modified in the loop. How could I solve it in a proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing elements from a container in a loop typically doesn't work.

I would suggest something along the lines of:

```py
org = current_user.Organization
org.items = [item for item in org.items if item.id not in remove_ids]
db.session.commit()
```